# Nullpointer exception after adding admob

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, admob

my program works fine but when i add admob i get nullpointer exception error
here is my code :

```
public class HomeActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements      OnRestResponseHandler, OnBackStackChangedListener, OnGetViewListener,  OnFragmentClickListener {

private InterstitialAd interstitial; 
private final String TAG = "HomeActivity";
private final String KEY_LIST_DATA = "list_cache";
private final String KEY_LIST_POSITION = "list_position";


private static ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private ArrayList<NodeCategory> mData;
private int mPosition = -1;
private boolean mIgnoreSelection = false;

@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(this);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    this.loadData(savedInstanceState);

    //ad
     // Create the interstitial.
    interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this);
    interstitial.setAdUnitId("XXXXXXX");

    // Create ad request.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

    // Begin loading your interstitial.
    interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
    //ad
     AdView adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest1 = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest1);



    //timer ad
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Invoke displayInterstitial() when you are ready to display an interstitial.

             if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                  interstitial.show();
                }

        }
        }, 5000);

    //ad


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        BitmapDisplayer displayer = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.config_enable_image_fade_in)
                ? new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.config_fade_in_time))
                : new SimpleBitmapDisplayer();

        final DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .displayer(displayer)
                .cacheInMemory()
                .cacheOnDisc()
                .build();

        final ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
                .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1)
                .offOutOfMemoryHandling()
                .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO)
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
                .build();

        mImageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        mImageLoader.init(config);
    }

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState) {
    if (this.mData != null) {
        outState.putSerializable(KEY_LIST_DATA, this.mData);
        outState.putInt(KEY_LIST_POSITION, this.mPosition);
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

public void loadData (Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Check Network State
    if (!NetworkUtil.getNetworkState(this)) {
        final RetryFragment fragment = RetryFragment.getFragmentWithMessage("No connection");
        this.addFragment(fragment, RetryFragment.TAG, true);
        return;
    }

    if (savedInstanceState == null || savedInstanceState.get(KEY_LIST_DATA) == null) {
        final String url = "http://something";
        if (url != null && URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)) {
            // Add Loading Fragment
            final LoadingFragment fragment = new LoadingFragment();
            this.addFragment(fragment, LoadingFragment.TAG, true);


            // Load Data
            final RestClientHandler handler = new RestClientHandler(this);
            RestClient.get(this, url, handler);
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Restored Instance");
        this.mData = (ArrayList<NodeCategory>) savedInstanceState.get(KEY_LIST_DATA);
        this.mPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_LIST_POSITION);
        if (this.mPosition != -1) {
            mIgnoreSelection = true;
        }

        this.configureActionBar();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResponse (ArrayList<NodeCategory> response) {
    this.mData = response;

    // Add ERROR Fragment
    if (this.mData == null) {
        final RetryFragment fragment = RetryFragment.getFragmentWithMessage();
        this.addFragment(fragment, RetryFragment.TAG, true);
        return;
    }

    if (this.mData.isEmpty()) {
        this.addFragment(null, null, true);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty Manifest!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    this.configureActionBar();
}


public void configureActionBar () {
    super.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    super.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    if (this.mData.size() == 1) {
        final NodeCategory node = this.mData.get(0);
        super.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        super.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(node.name);
        this.onCategorySelected(node);
    } else {
        super.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        super.getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        super.getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(new Adapter(this, this, this.mData), this);
        if (this.mPosition != -1) {
            this.mIgnoreSelection = true;
            super.getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(this.mPosition);
        }
    }
}


public void addFragment (SherlockFragment fragment, String tag, boolean clearStack) {
    final FragmentManager fm = super.getSupportFragmentManager();
    final FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();

    // Clear Back Stack
    if (clearStack) {
        for (int x = 0; x < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); x++) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        }
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        if (!clearStack) {
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, tag);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        } else {
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, tag);
        }

        try {
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected (int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Item Selection: " + itemPosition);
    this.mPosition = itemPosition;
    if (this.mIgnoreSelection == true) {
        this.mIgnoreSelection = false;
        return false;
    }

    this.onCategorySelected(this.mData.get(itemPosition));
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onCategorySelected (NodeCategory node) {
    final SherlockFragment frag = new CategoryFragment();
    final Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(CategoryFragment.BUNDLE_TAG, node.wallpaperList);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    this.addFragment(frag, CategoryFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG, true);
}

@Override
public void onWallpaperSelected (NodeWallpaper node) {
    final SherlockFragment frag = new WallpaperFragment();
    final Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(WallpaperFragment.BUNDLE_TAG, node);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    this.addFragment(frag, WallpaperFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG, false);
}

@Override
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, LayoutInflater mInflater) {
    final TextView t = new TextView(this);
    t.setText(this.mData.get(position).name);
    t.setTextSize(20);
    t.setPadding(5, 6, 2, 6);
    t.setSingleLine(true);
    return t;
}

@Override
public void onBackStackChanged () {
    final FragmentManager fm = super.getSupportFragmentManager();
    if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
        this.configureActionBar();
    }
}


private final String HIDE = "Hide Launcher Icon";
private final String SHOW = "Show Launcher Icon";
private final int HIDE_ID = 0;
private final int SHOW_ID = 1;

private final int FLAG_SHOW = PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED;
private final int FLAG_HIDE = PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED;
private final int DONT_KILL_APP = PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    menu.clear();
    menu.add(3, 3, 3, ((isShowing()) ? HIDE : SHOW)).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: {
            final FragmentManager fm = super.getSupportFragmentManager();
            fm.popBackStack();
            return true;
        }

        default: {
            if (item.getTitle().equals(SHOW)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Show");
                super.showDialog(SHOW_ID);
                return true;
            } else if (item.getTitle().equals(HIDE)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Hide");
                super.showDialog(HIDE_ID);
                return true;
            } else {
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog (int id) {
    if (id == HIDE_ID) {
        return (new AlertDialog.Builder(this)).setCancelable(true).setTitle("Hide App Icon").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setMessage("This option will remove the icon from your app drawer.").setPositiveButton("Remove", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                hideIcon();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).create();
    } else if (id == SHOW_ID) {
        return (new AlertDialog.Builder(this)).setCancelable(true).setTitle("Show App Icon").setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setMessage("This option will restore the icon into your app drawer.").setPositiveButton("Show", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                showIcon();
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).create();
    }

    return null;
}

public boolean isShowing () {
    PackageManager p = super.getPackageManager();
    return (p.getComponentEnabledSetting(getComponenetName()) == PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED || p.getComponentEnabledSetting(getComponenetName()) == PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT);
}

private void hideIcon () {
    getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponenetName(), FLAG_HIDE, DONT_KILL_APP);
}

private void showIcon () {
    getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponenetName(), FLAG_SHOW, DONT_KILL_APP);
}

private ComponentName getComponenetName () {
    ComponentName c = new ComponentName(this, LauncherActivity.class);
    return c;
}


   }
```

and here is log cat

```
02-23 14:50:00.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1531): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-23 14:50:00.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1531): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.safshari.wallpaperen/com.safshari.wallpaperen.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 14:50:00.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
02-23 14:50:00.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
02-23 14:50:00.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-23 14:50:00.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
02-23 14:50:00.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-23 14:50:00.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-23 14:50:00.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-23 14:50:00.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-23 14:50:00.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-23 14:50:00.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-23 14:50:00.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-23 14:50:00.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-23 14:50:00.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1531): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 14:50:00.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at com.safshari.wallpaperen.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:82)
02-23 14:50:00.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
02-23 14:50:00.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-23 14:50:00.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
02-23 14:50:00.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1531):     ... 11 more
```

where should i put my ads to dont get this error ?
the program works fine without ad and xml is working great this page is main layout .

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-23 14:50:00.491: E/AndroidRuntime(1531):     at com.safshari.wallpaperen.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:82)`

Comment: adView.loadAd(adRequest1);

Comment: line 82 is blank this was in line 81

Comment: @Soheyl you stacktrace says you have NPE @ line 82. Sure you din't edit your code before posting stacktrace?. `adView` could be null

Comment: check if adview with id adView exist in the layout

Comment: adView.loadAd(adRequest1) - check if adView is not null. It is possible if R.id.adView was not found in the activity